# Array.reject!, how does it work exactly?

Tags: ruby, arrays, object, iteration

I've made a very small ruby script today that makes use of regexes to track down certain content in files with a specific name and removes that content before adding its replacement. (Or else stuff would go wrong during iterations).

I'm not very used to ruby (only been using it since my vacation job started which is 1-2 weeks ago), but one of my habits is to avoid touching lists (or most other ADT's using indexes) while iterating over them (to remove the certain content), doesn't matter which language I'm using.

After some searching I found out about a few `Array` functions that could help. Right now, I'm using `Array.reject!` and the script works like I want it to work, but I honestly can't figure out why `Array.reject! {|line| line =~ regex }` does not have trouble with skipping objects in the array. These sources, [ruby-docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html) & [some random website](http://apidock.com/ruby/Array/reject!), confirm that the changes are applied **instantly** while iterating, which makes me wonder how it does not mess up... The lines that are being removed have no space/words between them, only `\n` brings the next one to its own line of course (but that's just part of the end of the strings).

Has anyone got a great explanation for this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`Array#reject!` uses a `for` loop to iterate over the array's elements. Here's the C code:

```
for (i = 0; i < RARRAY_LEN(ary); ) {
  VALUE v = RARRAY_PTR(ary)[i];
  if (RTEST(rb_yield(v))) {
    rb_ary_delete_at(ary, i);
    result = ary;
  } 
  else {
    i++;
  }
}
```

The interesting part is that `i` is not incremented in the `for` statement. If the block given to `reject!` evaluates to `true` the current element is removed and `ary[i]` automatically points to the next element. Only if it evaluates to `false`, `i` is incremented.

```
[a b c d].reject! {|x| x == b}

 0 <------- i # doesn't match => i++
[a b c d]

   1 <----- i # matches => delete ary[i]
[a b c d]

   1 <----- i # doesn't match => i++
[a c d]

     2 <--- i # doesn't match => finished
[a c d]
```

Comment: I think I replied on the wrong comment and you might not be notified, since you actually gave an answer before his post, just saying this to notify you that I've read/learned from your comment ;p.

Comment: Look at this excellent article: http://matthewcarriere.com/2008/06/23/using-select-reject-collect-inject-and-detect/

Answer (score 2):

Here's the source code for `ary_reject_bang`, the heart of the C implementation of `reject!`.

```
static VALUE
ary_reject_bang(VALUE ary)
{
    long i;
    VALUE result = Qnil;

    rb_ary_modify_check(ary);
    for (i = 0; i < RARRAY_LEN(ary); ) {
        VALUE v = RARRAY_PTR(ary)[i];
        if (RTEST(rb_yield(v))) {
            rb_ary_delete_at(ary, i);
            result = ary;
        }
        else {
            i++;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

`RARRAY_PTR` is a macro defined in `ruby.h`, that gives you access to the underlying C array  of a Ruby array. The actual removal is done with `rb_ary_delete_at`, which uses some other macros to keep the array in order:

```
VALUE
rb_ary_delete_at(VALUE ary, long pos)
{
    long len = RARRAY_LEN(ary);
    VALUE del;

    if (pos >= len) return Qnil;
    if (pos < 0) {
        pos += len;
        if (pos < 0) return Qnil;
    }

    rb_ary_modify(ary);
    del = RARRAY_PTR(ary)[pos];
    MEMMOVE(RARRAY_PTR(ary)+pos, RARRAY_PTR(ary)+pos+1, VALUE,
        RARRAY_LEN(ary)-pos-1);
    ARY_INCREASE_LEN(ary, -1);

    return del;
}
```

Comment: @Stephan,
Well, I didn't see that one coming...but it totally makes sense and is indeed a very useful implementation to remove objects safely. Thanks a lot for your explanations! I'd vote up if I had 15 rep :p - Solved